# Failed to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 Preview and Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Preview, when I am trying to uninstall it by rerunning vs_Enterprise.exe, in the end it gives me this:

[image]

I also installed Visual Studio 2017 RC, trying to uninstall in the same way it gives the same error message.

When I click 'Modify' from

[image]
It gives me this error:

[image]

Now both are stuck there, I can't remove them and also can't reinstall them.

I also tried the possible solutions which I can find from google, and none of these works:

1. Uninstall from  control panel:

   Can't find Visual Studio 2015 Preview and Visual Studio 2017 RC in control panel's Programs and Features window
2. Run vs_enterprise.exe by using the /uninstall /force command-line:

   can't find vs_enterprise.exe from Package Cache folders, somewhere like this: 
   "%ProgramData%\Package Cache",
3. Use VisualStudioUninstaller:

   This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install the VS 2017 RC on the Pc that already installed the VS “15” preview, the prior previews of Visual Studio "15" must be uninstalled first, so you not need to uninstall the VS “15” preview again. During installation of Visual Studio 2017 RC, a cleaning tool will automatically be run on your machine that will detect artifacts from a prior preview installation and then remove them, you can check [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) for Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-faq).

To uninstall the VS 2017 RC and VS "15" preview edition, you can try to directly remove those 3 folders: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview, %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017 and %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages, then re-run the VS 2007 RC installer as administrator, it should display as a new installation.

Comment: Thanks Sera, This doesn't work for me.

  First, I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 Preview 5 before I install Visual Studio 2017 RC, but the uninstall failed.

   Second, I click the icon beside the 'Lunch' and select 'Uninstall', it gives me a 'Setup Operation Failed' popup message.

Comment: @Gisway, you can try to directly remove those 3 folders: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview, %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017 and %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages, then re-run the VS 2007 RC installer as administrator, it should display as a new installation. If your still meet error, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: @Gisway, glad to hear that your issue is solved and I edited my previous reply, could you mark it as answer, so other community member who meet the same issue can directly search and confirm this solution.